# How to fix the issue of generated text field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular in my project, and I have this JSON object:

```
items={"departure":"New York","arrival":"California","stations":[{"station":"toto"},{"station":"titi"},{"station":"tata"}]}
```

I tried to populate this JSON object in the UI like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucxEO.png).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel-body panelcolor">

<div *ngIf="items?.departure">
<span>{{items.departure}}</span> --> 
<span *ngIf="items.stations.length > 0">
    {{items.stations[0].station}}
</span>
<span *ngIf="items.stations.length === 0">
    {{items.arrival}}
</span>

<div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" 
 type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" 
  type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>    

<div *ngFor="let item of items.stations; let i=index, let last = last">

<div *ngIf="!last">
    <span>{{item.station}}</span> --> <span *ngIf="items.stations[i+1]">{{items.stations[i+1].station}}</span>
    <div class="input-group spinner">
        <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
            <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>

</div>

<div *ngIf="items?.arrival && items?.stations.length > 0">
<span>{{items.stations[items.stations.length-1].station}}</span> --> <span>{{items.arrival}}</span>
<div class="input-group spinner">
    <input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceUp()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
        <button (click)="spinnerPriceDown()" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

spinnerPriceUp() function code :

```
spinnerPriceUp(){
let price=parseInt(`${this.myForm.value.price}`)+1;
this.myForm.controls['price'].setValue(price)
 }
```

spinnerPriceDown() function code :

```
 spinnerPriceDown(){
   if(parseInt(`${this.myForm.value.price}`) > 0){
    let price=parseInt(`${this.myForm.value.price}`)-1;
    this.myForm.controls['price'].setValue(price)
 }
}
```

My problem is when I try to click (up or down) the spinner to change the value of the text box, all the text boxes change their value. Can anyone help me to fix this problem? I tried to use form group to fix this issue but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Very close, but alas, I'm sure we've all fallen for this trick before...

All of your inputs controls are named "price", and your functions are modifying the formControl with a name of price.

You will either update the control in the formGroup's controls collection by index, or access the control by it's associated station.